# Apache2, PHP 5.2.8 Working - CRM Install Wizard Doesn't See the PHP Version

Tags: php, apache-2.2, crm

The Apache2 server and PHP version seem to be in order, but when I launch the CRM installer at

`http://localhost/<CRM dir>/install.php`

The wizard says I need a minimum of PHP 5.1 and preferably PHP 5.2.x.  The thing is, I am running PHP 5.2.8, and I know this from running

`php --version`

Plus, I spent a bunch of time learning how and (I thought, successfully) compiling PHP 5.2.8.  It is quite likely I screwed up and don't have some libraries I need, but I'm not sure where to look first.

Thanks in advance.

PS - I know some of you will suggest going to the CRM's forums...  I tried this; these are not good.  I much prefer the expertise I get here on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: what CRM are you using?

Comment: SugarCRM...  Trying to install 5.2.0l Community Edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line may run 5.2.8, but may have nothing to do with the cgi or module that apache runs. What does a webrequest with `<?php echo phpversion();?>` tell you about the version? Possibly use a full `phpinfo()` to check what's provided & where. Especially if you compiled a version of php by hand changes are high you did it only for the CLI package.

Comment: I am still new to this server configuration - can you explain more what you mean?  How would I do a webrequest for `<?php echo phpversion();?>`?  And/or how would I do a full `phpinfo()`?  I totally see what you mean, however, and I thought it might be something like this.  Thanks!

Comment: (1) create a file in your webdirectory (let's call it `test.php`). (2) Edit the file and enter `<?php echo phpversion();?>` (3) Open the url in your browser: http://yourdomain/test.php (e.g. http://localhost/test.php) and look at which version it reports.

Comment: OK, that worked and, as you suggested, it reported that I am using PHP 5.3.2, which is what I DON'T want!  Errgh...  Thanks again.  I have more work to do ;--)