# How To Change What Version of PHP Apache2 Uses?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, php.ini

Ubuntu 10.04, MySQL 5.1, Apache 2.2, and PHP 5.2/5.3:

I just discovered that I am using the wrong version of PHP for a CRM application.  Once I figured out how to make a simple `phpinfo()` script to tell me what Apache2 is using, I tried changing the `php.ini` such that my webserver would use the PHP I want.  Well, this is my problem.  Not sure how to do that.

I compiled the version of PHP I want to `/etc` here:

`/etc/php-5.2.8/`

Inside this, there was a `php.ini-recommended` file that I made some changes to and renamed to `php.ini` so PHP would use it.  But when I opened my browser and cleared my history and went to the `http://localhost<CRM dir>/install.php` address, the wizard still says I'm not usign the correct version of PHP.

Based on   [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/149013/apache2-php-5-2-8-working-crm-install-wizard-doesnt-see-the-php-version) what do I have to do to change the version of PHP that shows up after I run my `test.php` script?  In other words, `phpinfo()` says I'm running PHP 5.3.2, but I want to change it to my compiled 5.2.8 version located in `/etc`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on your server, you should be looking at Apache, not PHP.

**(For RHEL/CentOS) look at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.ini`**

```
#
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated web pages.
#
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
#
# Causes the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

You'll see that your PHP module is `modules/libphp5.so`.

`AddHandler php5-script .php` tells Apache to run PHP on any file with the extension `.php`.

If you are using an RPM based OS it's probably easier to uninstall (assuming you can do that) the current version of PHP, and reinstall the version you are looking for.

```
rpm -qa | grep php
```

will show you what version of PHP is currently installed.

Comment: It's worth mentioning you should bounce Apache after changing the config so it is picked up.

Comment: I really wish it was this easy.  The only `php.ini` file I have in the server directory is `/etc/apache2/php.ini` but not where you suggest.  This file doesn't have these components you speak of: LoadModule, AddHandler, AddType, etc.

Comment: interesting.   What OS flavor are you running on?  Was it configured via YUM, APT-Get, or YAST, (or some other package manager)?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.  The new version of PHP (5.3.2) can easily be installed unsing `apt-get`, which I have done.  But hte PHP 5.2.8 and 5.2.13 I compiled, using files from http://www.php.net/releases/.  I actually kind of gave up trying to get older version of PHP to run.  I think alternate approaches are in order for the sake of brevity.  Thanks for your help, nonetheless...

Comment: php.ini could be extended via includes: /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-php.conf:    LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7-zts.so

Answer (score 89):

If you've already installed another version of php, you only need to change the php* module used by apache.

for example, I have php5 and php7.0. when I want apache use php7.0, I only need to enable his module and disable php5 module.

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

Comment: This doesn't work if your Apache installation is not using the system php.

Comment: You can make your php installation system with module enable or scl if you use remi RPMs

Comment: also had to run `sudo a2dismod php7.2` to upgrade to php7.4 from php7.2

Answer (score 1):

There are two main methods to install a new PHP version and tell Apache to use it: `mod_php` and `php-fpm`.

**Note:** The preffered method is `php-fpm`, and many new distributions (including Fedora) are using it by default.

### Install PHP as Apache SAPI module

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) is the guide around this for Unix systems, from the official documentation. It has some missing points (at least for my setup), so I walk through the steps:

1. Build PHP from source. In the `./configure` step, use `--with-apxs2`. This will build shared Apache 2 handler module for you.

   Make sure you have `apxs` command defined in your path, or specify its path as the option's value (i.e. `--with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs`).

   For instance, if you installed Apache system-wide and want to install this command as well (e.g. on a local environment), on Fedora and its derivatives, you can install it by:

   ```
   sudo dnf install httpd-devel
   ```
2. After building is done (i.e. after `make` or `make test`), run `make install` (as root, perhaps). Obviously, this will install PHP to the path you specified (i.e. with `--prefix`).

   What is done just before PHP being installed is, because of the `--with-apxs2` option, installing PHP apache2handler SAPI module. It prepares the shared object (e.g. in `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp.so`), and activates the module (e.g. in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`), by adding one of the following lines to the Apache configuration file, depending on the PHP version you installed (the line is inserted below the section "Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support"):

   ```
   # In the case of PHP8
   LoadModule php_module           /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp.so

   # In the case of PHP7
   LoadModule php7_module          /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp.so
   ```

   **Note:** While switching on the PHP versions, specially major ones, keep in mind to check there is only one of these `LoadModule`s for PHP available, otherwise the Apache server refuses to start.

### Install PHP as PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager)

TBD. :)

### Final steps

#### PHP 8.0 and above extra step

In the case your distribution does not support PHP8 yet (e.g. Fedora 34) and you installed Apache2 from the package manager, you should take one more step.

The problem is, from PHP 8.0 onwards, Apache2 uses different identifiers for SAPI modules than before. These identifier are used in order to detect whether you are using `mod_php` or `php-fpm`, in the configuration files. For PHP5, it was `php5_module` and `mod_php5`; for PHP7, it is `php7_module` and `mod_php7`, and for PHP8, it is `php_module` and `mod_php`.

In this case, navigate to Apache2 configurations directory (e.g. `/etc/httpd`), and start editing the file `conf.d/php.conf`. There are two `IfModule` sections there: One for enabling `php-fpm` if you don't use `mod_php`, and the other for enabling `mod_php` if you are using it (i.e. using `LoadModule` somewhere in the configurations). You should update these conditions to cover PHP8 as well.

For instance, consider the following:

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
    # Enable PHP-FPM configuration
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

You should surround the core configuration with one more `IfModule` section like this:

```
    <IfModule !mod_php.c>
      # Enable PHP-FPM configuration
    </IfModule>
```

And do the same for the `mod_php` enabler configuration section as well.

#### Last step

Restart the Apache service:

```
service httpd restart
```

Now, `phpinfo()` should show you the new PHP version you just installed. You should be happy now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where phpinfo() would show version 7.0 even though I had upgraded to version 7.3. And it turns out I just had to [restart apache](https://linuxize.com/post/install-php-7-on-centos-7/).

I used `sudo systemctl restart httpd` on centos7