# Installed new version of php but Apache still using the old version

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I manually installed php 5.4 on Ubuntu 10.04. The old version was 5.3.2. Now if i check the php version it shows 5.4:

```
max@ubuntu:/etc/php5$ php -v
PHP 5.4.0 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2015 14:04:16)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

But if i load index.php file in /var/www/ the apache still shows that the php version is 5.3.2.

How to make apache recognize the new php 5.4 version?

Comment: you _MUST_ restart apache after upgrade

Comment: I did that. I even restarted the server but without effect.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is end of life. You should be upgrading to a supported Ubuntu version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Change What Version of PHP Apache2 Uses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/149039/how-to-change-what-version-of-php-apache2-uses)

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that you also installed apache module for new version then disable old one and enable new one

Here is example for php5 to php7

```
sudo a2dismod php5 
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

Of course after that restart apache

Comment: Heres a little explanation of how it works. ```a2dismod``` disables php5 from being used as default version by the server and  ```a2enmod``` sets php7.XX as default php version.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here, but a2dismod did not work. I solved it removing the old apache config from /etc/apache2/conf-enabled and adding the right one from conf-available

```
cd /etc/apache2/conf-enabled
sudo rm php5.6-fpm.conf
sudo ln -s ../conf-available/php7.2-fpm.conf
```

restart apache et voilà!

Comment: I had to remove the files from the mods-enabled directory for php

Comment: There is no folder `conf-enabled`

Comment: This solved my problem. In my case, there was `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php7.1-fpm.conf` that prevented me from using PHP 5.6. Even though I disabled PHP 7.1 and enabled PHP 5.6, it was still using PHP 7.1. So, I removed the `php7.1-fpm.conf` file and now Apache uses PHP 5.6.

Comment: This command will handle the above automatically: `sudo a2disconf php5.6-fpm`

Answer (score 0):

Try following one of these:

- [How to setup / install PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS | Dev Metal](http://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)
- [How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 10.04 and the method to add lines in sources.list doesn't work. And i already said that i installed php 5.4 manually. The problem is that Apache doesn't use the 5.4 version but the old version 5.3.2.

Comment: whichever way you installed is incorrect and this is why i'm pointing for you these documents, so you can follow them and get new php to work on your system

Comment: Why the manual install should be incorrect? I downloaded php-5.4.0.tar.gz file, then use these commands: `tar -xvf php-5.4.0.tar.gz`, `./configure`, `make`, `make install`. I didn't get any errors during the install. Using apt-get doesn't work, it always install php 5.3.2.

Comment: using `apt-get` is wiser then doing manual install, but if you still want to go ahead with manual install, you should read following http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

Answer (score -1):

Php support is added to apache by loading a proper library. If you installed or built this library for your new php version you have to change the apache config files to load the new library instead of the old one.