# How to point apache to the php binary used by the php docker image

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to use the [`php` docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) to set up an apache web server:

```
FROM php:7-alpine3.8
apk add apache2 php7-apache2
```

When I print `phpinfo()` from the webserver I see that it is running with the php version in `/usr/lib/php7`:

[image]

However, I've been trying to set up the dependencies using the `docker-php-ext-*` scripts provided by the php image, which seems to be modifying the php version installed in `/usr/local/etc/php`.

```
bash-4.4# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
```

What's going on here, shouldn't this work out of the box? According to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/149039/how-to-change-what-version-of-php-apache2-uses) I should be redirecting apache to a new `libphp*.so` file, but I have no such file anywhere in my docker instance;

```
bash-4.4# find / -type f -name "libphp*.so"
bash-4.4#
```

Comment: If you intended to use a combined PHP/Apache Docker image, why don't you use the one already provided, rather than trying to create your own?

Comment: @MichaelHampton are you saying I wouldn't have this issue if I used one of the Apache images?

Comment: Nope, it just works out of the box. Use `php:7-apache` and move on to whatever you were really trying to do.

Comment: @MichaelHampton your suggestion was good - had some issues after using that image but they were all surmountable. Cheers.